# Regular Expression to match sentences

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make a regular expression in python that matches sentences. The one I see that mostly works is: `[^\.\?\!].*?[\.\?\!]`  ,but with the test sentences below it has a few errors. You can see using the site https://regex101.com/. I'm looking for a regular expression that encompasses all the problems below such as ellipsis, honorifics, and the i.e. thing.

> For performing tokenization in languages other than English, we can
>   load the respective language pickle file found in tokenizers/punkt and
>   then tokenize the text in another language, which is an argument of
>   the tokenize() function. For the tokenization of French text, we will
>   use the french.pickle file as follows: Mr. Smith bought cheapsite.com
>   for 1.5 million dollars, i.e. he paid a lot for it. Did he mind? Adam
>   Jones Jr. thinks he didn't. In any case, this isn't true... Well, with
>   a probability of .9 it isn't.

p.s. If you're wondering I got the above sentences from a natural language processing book and another stack overflow question on the same subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way is to split it in 3 operations.

- substitute i.e., ellipsis and what ever you want with other markers without dots like `@@@ie@@@` and `@@@ellipsis@@@`.
- match sentences.
- After that rebuild i.e. and ellipsis.

**Update:** Some code how to do it. You have to do the substitutions for each item with dots you want to exclude from the sentence-matcher.

```
sentences = re.sub(r'i\.e\.', "@@@ie@@@", sentences);
matches = re.match(r'[^\.\?\!].*[\.\?\!]', sentences);
matches = re.sub(r'@@@ie@@@', "i.e.", matches);
```

Comment: Yes, and how you will do it?

Comment: Ok, but keep in mind that it isn't so simple since for each language you have to deal with a thousand words dictionary (at least) with dots, and doing that for thousand or more substrings can't be done this way if you want something efficient.

Comment: You're right. But there is no other way in regular expression to deal with dots that are not the end of a sentence because a dot is a dot in regexp. For extensive usecases you have to deal with NLP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing